# Limit for Text Analytics Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

I'm using Azure Text Analytics for Sentiment Analysis. I was wondering if the API is limited to 100 requests per minute or if there is any request limit for the service.

When I tried to request more than 100 times within a minute, the API returns an empty document.

Comment: The rate limit is 100 calls per minute. Note that you can submit a large quantity of documents in a single call (up to 1000 documents).  Check the Data Limits item https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Text-Analytics/overview

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Text-Analytics/overview:

**Limits**

Maximum size of a single document: 5,000 characters as measured by String.Length.

Maximum size of entire request: 1 MB

Maximum number of documents in a request:   1,000 documents

The rate limit is 100 calls per minute. Note that you can submit a large quantity of documents in a single call (up to 1000 documents).

Comment: It seems that the request payload size is now limited to 524288 characters. This is not reflected in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This poster has similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359508/rate-limit-exceeded-in-face-api) and developed their own ratelimiter for cognitive services.